# clang dangling reference?

Tags: c

My function is giving out 'dangling reference' warnings, ie:

```
int mode_pos = 0, mode;
static char *s;
char buffer[FAT_BUFFER + 1];

chan->i_mode = chan->mode;
buffer[0] = 0;
s = buffer;
mode = chan->mode;

if (!mode)
        return NULL;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'buffer' is still referred to by the global variable 's' upon returning to the caller. This will be a dangling reference

Is this serious, and what's the best way to actually correct it?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have design problem, here. If `s` is really only used inside that one function and uncondionally set to `buffer`, there is no point at all to have it `static`. If this is so, this dangling reference isn't a very dangerous one, either, but better clean up your code to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is serious.
It causes **Undefined Behavior**. lifetime of `buffer` is limited to scope(`{`,`}`) of the function and it may/may not live beyond the function body. It may seem to work sometimes and might fail sometimes.It is not guaranteed to work and you would expect your program to work in a defined manner.So it should be avoided.

You need to define `buffer` in such a way so that it lifetime increases beyond the function body. There are two ways to do this:

1. You dynamic memory allocation using `malloc()` (Caller should remember to `free()` it) or
2. Declare `buffer` as `static` local.

Comment: I went ahead and just made buffer static :) Thank you!